# How to disable only telephone network?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, calls, networking, mobile-network

Is it possible to disable only the telephone network and not internet network, so as to use the smartphone as a tablet with a only SIM data?

I use Android 6.0 and I have no possibility to use wi-fi, I need to go on the web with the SIM data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the desired result bu removing your SIM card and connecting your phone to WiFi.

But using a SIM card and using only internet network and not telephone network is not possible.

Comment: I edit the question because I have no possibility to use WI-FI